# 0xC000005 Access Violation when reading, using strcmp in C

Tags: c, string, multidimensional-array

i am a beginner in C and i am writing a program to find the frequency of character in string. I encounter an access violation here but i am unable to solve it. Its in the while loop that i am looping to get each unique char found in the string array and storing it in another. Can i have some help here? Thanks in advance.

```
int main()
{
    char str[5][10];
    int i=0, j=0, k, l=0;
    char chh[10];
    strcpy(chh, "a");   while (l < 5)
{

    if (strcmp(chh[i],str[l][j]) != 0) <--- access violation in this line.
    {
        chh[i] == str[l][j];
        i++;
    }

    if (j >= 9)
        j = 0;
        l++;

    j++;
 }




}
```

Comment: `str` is completely uninitialized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using strcmp to compare two characters.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/

```
int strcmp ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );
```

you should just remove that strcmp and compare the two characters directly

```
chh[i] == str[l][j]
```

**EDITED**

And you probably want

```
if (j >= 9){
    j = 0;
    l++;
}
```